# Java commands runs on bash, fails on zsh

Tags: bash, shell, java, zsh

Consider the following command which runs flawlessly using `bash`:

```
java -classpath bin:lib/* FunctionalTests.TestRunner
```

The classes are in `bin`, jars are in `lib`, `main()` is in `bin/FunctionalTests/TestRunner`:

```
.
├── bin
├── lib
│   ├── commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
│   ├── commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
│   ├── commons-io-2.1.jar
│   ├── commons-lang-2.4.jar
│   ├── commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
│   └── ...
└── src
```

When the same command runs with `zsh`, the output is:

```
zsh: no matches found: ./bin:./lib/*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the bin and lib folders subdirectories of your current directory?

Comment: Yes - I'll add the dir structure.

Comment: Based on this post, it looks like zsh has some wierd glob behavior http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5572/scp-globbing-and-different-shells

Comment: @ColinD I can’t call “don’t launch command if pattern match failed” “weird”. It is “explicit is better then implicit”: if you don’t need globbing, do escape globbing characters. If you do need globbing, use glob characters, but prepare to errors if globbing fails. You can use `*(N)` to make zsh remove pattern if it fails (`(N)` sets option NULL_GLOB for current pattern). And, of course, you can use options to make zsh behave just as weird as POSIX shells.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It boils down to another pair of quotes:

```
java -classpath "bin:lib/*" FunctionalTests.TestRunner
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Comment: Zsh treats nonmatching fileglobs as errors, bash returns them as they are. So `echo *nosuchfile` is error in zsh but it prints "*nosuchfile" in bash. Zsh has an option to change this behavior.

Comment: And bash has an option to be like `zsh`, too: `shopt -s failglob`.

Comment: The problem with this seems to be that zsh does not expand environment variables when they are inside the quote. So this does not work:
`java -cp "$M2_REPO/com/h2database/h2/1.3.159/h2*.jar:$M2_REPO/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.1.1/*.jar" liquibase.integration.commandline.Main`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use something like this to add every .jar in the classpath:

```
CP=bin
for i in lib/*.jar
do
  CP=$CP:${i}               
done
java -classpath $CP FunctionalTests.TestRunner
```

Comment: why are you using ls instead of `for i in lib/*.jar`? http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: You are right, this solution is better, I'm fixing my post, thanks a lot